# converting ddmmyy into mmyy format by using pandas?

Tags: pandas

i have column(month) in the ddmmyy format, how i can convert that into mmyy format.

Month
6/1/2017
5/1/2017
 i have used below code, can someone help

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\UK_IYA.csv")
df['Month']=pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%d/%m/%y')
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\my test.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert column to datetimes in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) by parameter `parse_dates` and `dayfirst` and then convert to custom format by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\UK_IYA.csv", parse_dates=['Month'], dayfirst=True)
df['Month']= df['Month'].dt.strftime('%b %y')
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\my test.csv")
```

Your code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\UK_IYA.csv")
df['Month']=pd.to_datetime(df['Month'],format='%d/%m/%y').dt.strftime('%b %y')
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\venkagop\Subbu\my test.csv")
```

**Sample**:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Month,sale
05/03/12,2
05/04/12,4
05/05/12,6
05/06/12,8"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['Month'], dayfirst=True)
print (df)
       Month  sale
0 2012-03-05     2
1 2012-04-05     4
2 2012-05-05     6
3 2012-06-05     8
df['Month']= df['Month'].dt.strftime('%b %y')
print (df)
    Month  sale
0  Mar 12     2
1  Apr 12     4
2  May 12     6
3  Jun 12     8
```

Comment: i have tried , but iam gettting in the below format
117
117
117
117
117

Comment: Use `.dt.strftime('%b %y')` instead `.dt.strftime('%m%y')`

Comment: its working but when i have applied filter on the excel its showing only  2018 but i  have data in excel for 2016&2017 as well.

Comment: @subbu - There is some problem in excel, need filter by last to letter for `18`

Comment: not sure how i can overcome this issue, after execution if apply filter to validate the data then iam facing problem apart from this everything is fine.

Comment: code is perfectly fine, problem in excel. now its perfectly working.

Comment: code is perfectly fine, problem in excel. now its perfectly working.

Comment: @subbu - Super, glad can help!